# What is the advantage of an object type with a different reference type in Java?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, types, polymorphism

I know that when dealing with polymorphism in Java, you can have a different declared type for an object than the object type. For example:

```
    Parent foo = new Child();
```

I mostly see it when the declared type is an interface such as:

```
    Map<Integer,BigInteger> memo = new TreeMap<Integer,BigInteger>();
```

I see this a lot in peoples Java code. What is the benefit of declaring foo as a Parent when it is a Child object? I also understand that if we do this, foo can no longer call any methods that are not declared abstract or defined in Parent. What puzzles me is I see this done when we can have both the declared and actual type Child and still pass as an argument to methods which require a Parent parameter object. For example:

```
    Child fooNew = new Child();
    public void showObj(Parent o){
        System.out.println(o); }
    showObj(fooNew);
```

*So what gives?* In what circumstance would it be beneficial to have different declared and actual types for an object? My book says its important for generic programming but doesn't explain. I see it consistently used but with no clue why. And it even seems to have some drawbacks of its own.

Comment: Read from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat The principle is the same.

Comment: It makes sense when a parent has multiple children overriding one or more of parents methods. You can put instances of different children in some collection defined with parent type and when overridden method is called, JVM will appropriately call this method for each child instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Parent foo = new Child();
```

advantage comes in play when you realise later that there is a better child available to use. So without changing any other piece of code, you can just use your better child:

```
Parent foo = new BetterChild();
```

`BetterChild` should obviously be a child of `Parent`

Answer (score 0):

You might have many classes that inherit from the `Parent` class. The `foo` variable can store an instance of any of these classes, and the code using it can be general (i.e. it can work without knowing which specific sub-class of Parent is being used).

The same is true for using variables of an interface type (such as Map) and storing in them references to instances implementing that interface.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on "the code using it can be more general".

Comment: @bmcentee148 If the code relies only of methods of the interface/super-class that that is used as the variable type, it can work with many different implementations of the interface or sub-classes of the super-class (even if those implementations haven't been developed yet at the time the code that can use them was written).

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to get it.